# std::string.c_str() returning a weird characters

Tags: visual-c++, char, stdstring

In my project, I use to load textures by specifying its file name. Now, I made this function `const char* app_dir(std::string fileToAppend);` that returns the `main`s `argv[0]` and change the application name by the `fileToAppend`. Since I cannot make the string manipulation easy with a char*, I use the `std::string`. My texture loader takes a const char* for file name so need to switch back to c_str(), now it generates a sequence of ASCII symbol characters (bug). I already fix the problem by changing the return type of the `app_dir()` to `std::string`. But why is that happening?

**EDIT**

sample code:

```
//in main I did this

extern std::string app_filepath;

int main(int argc, char** arv) {

    app_filepath = argv[0];

    //...

}

//on other file

std::string app_filepath;

void remove_exe_name() {

    //process the app_filepath to remove the exe name

}

const char* app_dir(std::string fileToAppend) {

    string str_app_fp = app_filepath;

    return str_app_fp.append(fileToAppend).c_str();

    //this is the function the generates the bug

}
```

I already have the functioning one by changing its return type to std::string as I said earlier.

Comment: Can you clarify your question by posting the concerned code?

Comment: Please provide your code , it would be easier root cause it from reading the code

Comment: @Telkitty a look now at my edit.

Comment: @ShmilTheCat look now at my edit.

Answer (score 1):

When you using function **const char* app_dir(std::string fileToAppend);** you get pointer to the memory that allocated on the stack and already deleted when the function ends.

Comment: I use `app_dir` on some function like `PNG_LoadTexture(app_dir("Images\\backgroun1.png"), ...);`

Answer (score 1):

A big no no :) returning pointer to local objects

```
return str_app_fp.append(fileToAppend).c_str();
```

Change your function to

```
std::string app_dir(const std::string& fileToAppend) {

string str_app_fp = app_filepath + fileToAppend;

return str_app_fp;
```

}

And on the return value use c_str()

Comment: Yes, that was what I did also. But can you explain why a return type of `const char*` did some bugs after returning a `std::string.c_str();` ??

Comment: Sure, in your original code you declared local std::string object on the stack, indeed some memory was _dynamically_ allocated in order to hold the appended path, but when the function returned the std::string destructor was called and all the allocated memory was freed and you left w/ a stall pointer to free memory area hence you saw the garbage

Comment: not the code but the the comment you given is the real answer I'm looking for.